# Dynamically get Modified fields in trigger

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

We have a case with 100 fields if i updated 1 or 2 fields, to know that field iterating all 100 fields. How to get that field without iterating 100 fields.

Below Trigger was implemented

```
trigger fields on Case (before update) {

Map<string, Schema.SobjectField> caseFields = Schema.SObjectType.Case.fields.getMap();
case caseold = trigger.old[0];

if(caseold.get(fieldName) != null)
For (Case cs : Trigger.new) {

    for (string fieldName : caseFields.keySet()) {

        if ( cs.get(fieldName) != Trigger.oldMap.get(cs.id).get(fieldName)) {
            string oldvalue = string.valueOf(caseold.get(fieldName));

            string newvalue= string.valueOf(cs.get(fieldName));

            cs.IterateField__c = 'Changed '+fieldName +' From '+oldvalue +' to '+newvalue;
            system.debug('Changed field values:'+ cs.IterateField__c);
        }  
    }
}
```

}

But, faced issue those trigger for iterating all fields. I want to iterating only Modified fields.anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it through trigger, an alternate solution is to use [Change data capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) feature of salesforce. with summer 2019 you can write trigger on CDC for any object.

It just gives you a json with just changed fields.

> Receive near-real-time changes of Salesforce records, and synchronize
>   corresponding records in an external data store. Change Data Capture
>   publishes change events, which represent changes to Salesforce
>   records. Changes include creation of a new record, updates to an
>   existing record, deletion of a record, and undeletion of a record

It's a paid feature with configuration options for salesforce objects which can be propagated to middleware/external system

documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_select_objects.htm):